# Does anyone know where I can get a copy of Gaunce Lewis's thesis?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

Tracing through a trail of references I found myself needing something proven in Appendix A of "The Stable Category and Generalized Thom Spectra" by Gaunce Lewis (I believe this was his thesis at UChicago under Peter May, from 1978). My library doesn't seem to have a copy and I can't find anything online. Does anyone know where I could find this?

Before anyone suggests it, I'll remark that I can't contact Lewis himself because he passed away several years ago. I guess I'm hoping Peter May will come on here and know where a copy can be found.

Comment: Peter May does appear on here occasionally. Can't you contact the math department at Chicago? They must have a copy, though maybe not in electronic form.

Comment: Whatever you're looking for may well be proven in LMS but with a G everywhere...

Comment: There is a copy available at Crerar Library at Chicago. I'll stop by this evening and scan the appendix for you.

Comment: @Alex: in light of the answer below it appears that scanning it in won't be necessary. Thanks for your kind offer, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peter has been so kind to scan it a while ago. Maybe he has already put it on his webpage. Here is another link that should work.

http://www.math.ku.dk/~xvd217/Compactly%20Generated%20Spaces-MAY.pdf

Comment: The link you posted (and the logical variations of it I tried) generates a 403 error for me. Perhaps it is only available on your local network?

Comment: I was also forbidden to access it

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks to Markus and Dan for providing this

Answer (score 4):

My apologies to everyone, and especially to Markus.  He got me to get this scanned, and I sent him a copy; I also promised to put it on my web page, but I only just now did so: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/GaunceApp.pdf

Alex, that would be nice, and drop in and say hello some time.

Unfortunately, I do not actually have a copy of Gaunce's thesis, so what is posted is only Appendix A, ``Compactly generated spaces''.  Most, maybe all, of the rest evolved into much of Springer Lecture Notes Vol 1213, http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/equi.pdf

Gaunce's thesis was 1978, and SLN 1213 only appeared in 1986.  We did a ton of work in that time, and I doubt that there would be much besides Appendix A that is of current interest.
However, Appendix A is to my mind (and the minds of others) the nicest and most informative treatment of compactly generated spaces, and that part is not at all duplicated in SLN 1213.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the links. I look forward to reading this, now that I have it.

Comment: This is relevant to the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127841/128362#128362

I mentioned there Peter Johnson'e paper on a "Topologiacal Topos", and I notice that this idea is endorsed by Gaunce in his final section of the Appendix. 