# Compact-open Topology for Partial Maps?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

I asked [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802488/compact-open-topology-for-partial-maps) on MathStackExchange a month ago and received no answer. I feel that this would be more suitable for MathOverflow.

[Compact open topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130287/compact-open-topology) is one of the most common ways of turning the set of continuous maps between two topological spaces into a topological space. Suppose $X, Y$ are topological spaces, and let $K\subseteq X$ be a compact subset and $U\subseteq Y$ be an open subset. $$V_{K, U}=\{f: X\to Y \mid f(K)\subseteq U\}$$ Then the collection of all such $V_{K, U}$ is a subbase for the compact-open topology on $C(X, Y).$

A [partial map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Function_spaces) $f: X\rightharpoonup Y$ is a function from some subset $X_f\subseteq X$ to $Y.$ To define continuity  in this context, consider the totalization
$$\widetilde{f}(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x\in X_f$} \\
\star, & \text{if $x\notin X_f$}
\end{cases}$$ where $\star\notin Y,$ and equip $\widetilde{Y}=Y\cup\{\star\}$ with the smallest topology extending that of $Y.$ i.e., $U\subseteq \widetilde{Y}$ is open iff $U=\widetilde{Y}$ or $U$ is open in $Y.$ Then claim $f: X\rightharpoonup Y$ is continuous iff $\widetilde{f}: X\to\widetilde{Y}$ is continuous. Observe that this definition doesn't alter the continuity of total maps.

Now, I want to understand how we can have a nice topology on the set of all continuous partial maps between $X$ and $Y.$ Since there is a bijection between $\{X\rightharpoonup Y\}$ and $\{X\to \widetilde{Y}\},$ I'm thinking that we can simply look at the compact-open topology on $C(X, \widetilde{Y}).$ But I'm not sure that this is the correct/best way to topologize the space of partial maps. I need the opinion of somebody who has some experience in this area.

- Are there other ways of defining continuity for partial maps?
- If so, how is this topology different from those?
- Has anyone studied this problem before?

Comment: Another possibility, not sure how useful, would be to view partial maps as _functional_ relations, those relations $R\colon X\to Y$ such that $R(a)$ has at most one element for each $a\in A$. Then we could apply some of the stuff that has been developed for relations between topological spaces, their continuity, and the spaces of maps between them.

Comment: For example, the definitions of lower semicontinuous and upper semicontinuous relations [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440811) would lead to two other notions of continuity, which may or may not agree with the definition you gave (I haven't checked). We could also view relations as maps $\mathcal{P}(X)\to Y$, and use one of the topologies on $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{P}(X),Y)$, choosing one for $\mathcal{P}(X)$ too (there are many choices) if needed. Then we use the subspace topology on the subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{P}(X),Y)$ spanned by the partial maps/functional relations

Comment: This should lead to a bunch of different notions and potential definitions/topologies, but I'm not sure how useful this point of view might be

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to promote function space topologies so that convergence of nets behaves the way that one would expect it to behave. There are probably other ways of getting a topology for spaces of partial functions.

Suppose that $X,Y$ are topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq P(X)$. Suppose that $A_{R}\subseteq Y^X$ whenever $R\in\mathcal{C}$. Give each space $A_R$ a topology $\mathcal{T}_R$, and suppose that the restriction mapping $j_{R,S}:A_R\rightarrow A_S$ is continuous whenever $R,S\in\mathcal{C},S\subseteq R$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{C}}A_R$ where $U\in\mathcal{T}$ precisely when $U\cap A_R$ is open in $A_R$ for each $R\subseteq X$ and whenever $S\subseteq R$, we have $j_{R,S}^{-1}[U\cap A_S]\subseteq U\cap A_R$. The canonical basis for the topology on $\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{C}}A_R$ consists of the sets of the form $\bigcup_{R\supseteq S}j_{R,S}^{-1}[U]$ where $U$ is open in $A_S$. Therefore, the topology $\mathcal{T}_R$ is the subspace topology inherited from $\mathcal{T}$.

Proposition: A net $(f_d)_{d\in D}$ in the space $\bigcup_{R\subseteq X}A_R$ converges to a function $f$ if and only if there exists some $d\in D$ where
$\text{Dom}(f)\subseteq\text{Dom}(f_e)$ whenever $e\geq d$ and where the net
$(f_e|_{\text{Dom}(f)})_{e\in D,e\geq d}$ converges to $f$ in the topology $(A_\text{Dom}(f),\mathcal{T}_\text{Dom}(f))$.

Proof:

$\rightarrow$ Suppose that $(f_d)_{d\in D}\rightarrow f$ in $\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{C}}A_R$. Let $U=\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{C},R\supseteq\text{Dom}(f)}A_R$. Then there exists some $d\in D$ where if $e\geq d$, then $f_e\in U$. But this implies that if $e\geq d$, then $\text{Dom}(f_e)\supseteq\text{Dom}(f)$. Suppose now that $O\in\mathcal{T}_{\text{Dom}(f)}$ and $f\in O$. Then $\bigcup_{R\subseteq\text{Dom}(f)}j_{R,\text{Dom}(f)}^{-1}[O]\in\mathcal{T}$ and $f\in\bigcup_{R\subseteq\text{Dom}(f)}j_{R,\text{Dom}(f)}^{-1}[O]$. Therefore, since $(f_d)_{d\in D}\rightarrow f$, there exists some $d_1\in D$ with $d_1\geq d$ where $f_e\in\bigcup_{R\subseteq\text{Dom}(f)}j_{R,\text{Dom}(f)}^{-1}[O]$ whenever $e\geq d_1$. However, since $f_e\in\bigcup_{R\subseteq\text{Dom}(f)}j_{R,\text{Dom}(f)}^{-1}[O]$, we know that
$f_e|_{\text{Dom}(f)}=j_{\text{Dom}(f_e),\text{Dom}(f)}(f_e)\in O$. From this fact, we know that $(f_e|_{\text{Dom}(f)})_{e\geq d_1}$ converges to $f$ in the topology $(A_\text{Dom}(f),\mathcal{T}_\text{Dom}(f))$.

$\leftarrow.$ Suppose that $O\in\mathcal{T}$ and $f\in O$. Let $U=O\cap X_{\text{Dom}(f)}$. Then $U\in \mathcal{T}_{\text{Dom}(f)}$. Let $V=\bigcup_{R\supseteq\text{Dom}(f)}j_{R,\text{Dom}(f)}^{-1}[U]$. Then $V\in\mathcal{T}$ and $V\subseteq O$. Since there is some $d\in D$ where $\text{Dom}(f)\subseteq\text{Dom}(f_e)$ for $e\geq d$ and where $(f_e|_{\text{Dom}(f)})_{e\geq d}$ converges to $f$ in the topology $\mathcal{T}_{\text{Dom}(f)}$, we know that there is some $d_1\geq d$ where if $e\geq d_1$, then $f_e|_\text{Dom}(f)\in U$. But this implies that $f_e\in V\subseteq O$ whenever $e\geq d_1$. We conclude that $(f_d)_{d\in D}$ converges to $f$ in the space $\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{C}}A_R$.

Q.E.D.

The topology $\mathcal{T}$ is not $T_1$ whenever there are $R,S\in\mathcal{C}$ with $R\subseteq S,R\neq S$. Let $\leq$ be the specialization ordering with respect to the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Then we observe that $f\geq f|_R$ whenever $R\in\mathcal{C},R\subseteq\text{Dom}(f)$. Since the specialization ordering is not the equality relation, we conclude that the topology $\mathcal{T}$ is not $T_1$.

If you are looking for a different topology on spaces of partial functions, one can always associate the partial functions with their graphs which are closed subsets of $X\times Y$, but we can give the collection of closed subsets of $X\times Y$ various topologies such as the Vietoris topology.