# Compact set covered by two opens

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

The following lemma about locally compact (but not necessarily Hausdorff) spaces or continuous lattices appears frequently but without citation. It is easy to prove but important in proofs.

If a compact subspace is covered by two open subspaces, $K\subset U_1\cup U_2$, then there are compact subspaces $L_1$ and $L_2$ and open ones $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $K\subset V_1\cup V_2$, $V_1\subset L_1\subset U_1$ and $V_2\subset L_2\subset U_2$.

The earliest occurrence that I know is in *Adjoint Product and Hom Functors in General Topology* by Peter Wilker in *Pacific Journal of Mathematics* **34**(1970)269--283.  This paper was part of the development of [giving ${\mathbf{Top}}(X,Y)$ an approprate topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127841/giving-topx-y-an-appropriate-topology/127853#127853).

Was this property identified any earlier than 1970?

The definition of **locally compact** that I use is that if $x\in U$ then there are $K$ and $V$ with $x\in V\subset K\subset U$ (with similar letter conventions as above). This definition was stated in *Local Compactness and Continuous Lattices* by
Karl Hofmann and Michael Mislove in *Continuous Lattices* edited by Bernhard Banaschewski and Rudolf-Eberhard Hoffmann (NB different spelling), Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics, **871** (1981) 209--248.

However, the Wilker paper is not specifically about local compactness in this sense, even though he anticipates many of the ideas of continuous lattices and the Scott topology.

The context in which I ask the question is a draft paper of mine entitled
[*Local Compactness and Bases in various formulations of Topology*](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/loccbv/).

Comment: In the absence of Hausdorffness, there are various notions of local compactness. Some authors (e.g., Munkres) define a space to be locally compact if every point has a compact neighborhood. A stronger definition is that every point has a neighborhood basis consisting of compact neighborhoods; I expect it's the latter definition that Paul means here since he mentions continuous lattices (the topology of a locally compact space in this sense is a continuous lattice). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space.